# Tomcat 8 Docx4j application issues

Tags: java, tomcat, client-server, docx4j

I'm puzzled and need clever suggestions.

I have this Java 8 web application developed with Spring Boot which runs on an Apache Tomcat server, have a Postgresql database, and make use of a RabbitMq to handle requests made via a JS client, Swagger for the exposed REST API. The main purpose is to exploit common libs like docx4j and ApachePOI to read/write excel/word files on the system.

Everything works like a charm on a local installation.
But moving to a different environment with a central server and multiple hosts (2-3 at least) accessing the client app, makes it troublesome.

The main problem seems related to Tomcat since there is the constant need to restart the main application many times.
Also Tomcat process memory keeps growing. (All streams are properly closed after any use).

No errors are thrown or logged.

Already tried to force garbage collection (even if not recommended) where possible with no improvements.
Already tried to change server (Wildfly) with no improvements.
Tried on different OS environment with no changes.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

-- EDIT

Added APR support to Tomcat for better performance, still nothing. I've found a possible bottleneck in a function which makes intese use of docx4j libs for document merging. But it occurs only in this Windows environment.

Comment: Attach a profiler (such as [visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/)) to it and see what's going on.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question with no obvious answers.  Why are you restarting Tomcat?  Is it truly out of memory or is it hanging?  Have you profiled the application to see if there are memory leaks?  Have you tried to have 2-3 people access the app locally an see what happens?  I'd encourage a bit more debugging first.  The fact that it happens on multiple app servers makes makes me think it's something in your code.

Comment: @Kayaman Already attached visualvm, but nothing out of the normal.Ty

Comment: @stdunbar Yes I know it's really broad, just asking for clever suggestions. Already tried to made user access the local installation. Ty

Comment: @mguarnaccia how long did you observe? I'd expect you to see something interesting with it, before you need to reboot the server. Unless you mean you attached visualvm to your local installation, which doesn't have any problems.

Comment: @Kayaman I am re-running VisualVM to give you proper answers now.Ty

Comment: Can you please define the terms "troublesome" and "dizzy"? Those aren't widely-understood software-engineering terms. Is there an actual problem, or do you just get the sense that Tomcat is going to vomit any second from its presyncope?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz you're right, my bad. application get stuck. Server startup is ok, application is up and running and can process well any request, until tomcat process reaches 4GB of memory. no other input is processed and current thread is suspended, this is what happens.

Comment: Stuck? Thread dump. Log messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

All issues are related to application memory handling, not the environment.
I have replicated the "troublesome" environment to a different machine and still getting errors. So it is the application itself.

Thank you all for your time.